# Submit form with jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to learn MVC and one the things I want to do is submit a form to an action in my controller and this action will return the submitted data. Sounds simple but I've been trying for hours without any success.
my view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("BlogComment","Blog"))
 {
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <legend class="AddAComment">Add a comment</legend>

    <div class="commentformwrapper">

        <div class="editor-text">
        <span class="editor-label">User Name:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-text">
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        </div>

        <div class="editor-text">
        <textarea id="comment" rows="6" cols="23"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddendate" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Create" />

    </div>
}
```

my controller:

```
[HttpPost]   
public ActionResult CommentForm(Comment comment)
{
    Comment ajaxComment = new Comment();
    ajaxComment.CommentText = comment.UserName;
    ajaxComment.DateCreated = comment.DateCreated;
    ajaxComment.PostId = comment.PostId;
    ajaxComment.UserName = comment.UserName;

    mRep.Add(ajaxComment);
    uow.Save();
    //Get all the comments for the given post id

    return Json(ajaxComment);
}
```

and my js:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('form').submit(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CommentForm")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {
                    PostId: $('.postid').val(),
                    UserName: $('#username').val(),
                    DateCreated: new Date(),
                    CommentText: $('#comment').val()
                },
                success: function (result) {

                    alert("success " + result.UserName);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Failed");
                }
            });
          return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is your problem? What is not working?

Comment: you are missing JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically you are passing javascript object literals directly. So, before you pass data to your controller, it must be in `JSON` format(because you have specified application/json. see your $.ajax call). 
SO, you are missing JSON.stringify()

```
data: JSON.stringify({
                        PostId: $('.postid').val(),
                        UserName: $('#username').val(),
                        DateCreated: new Date(),
                        CommentText: $('#comment').val()
                    }),
```

OR

```
var someObj = {
            PostId: $('.postid').val(),
            UserName: $('#username').val(),
            DateCreated: new Date(),
            CommentText: $('#comment').val()
        };

         $.ajax({
            /// your other code
            data: JSON.stringify(someObj),
            // your rest of the code

        });
```

Answer (score 23):

You don't need to write any client side code to do this, FYI.

To use the ajax methods successfully in MVC, you will need to do the following. Add this key to appsettings in web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

As well as include the unobtrusive ajax script:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then create div container around your form and replace Html.BeginForm with Ajax.BeginForm

```
<div id="ajaxReplace">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BlogComment", "Blog", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ajaxReplace", OnSuccess = "doFunctionIfYouNeedTo", OnFailure = "ShowPopUpErrorIfYouWant" }))
 {
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <legend class="AddAComment">Add a comment</legend>

        <div class="commentformwrapper">

            <div class="editor-text">
            <span class="editor-label">User Name:</span>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-text">
            <input type="text" id="username" />
            </div>

            <div class="editor-text">
            <textarea id="comment" rows="6" cols="23"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddendate" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Create" />

        </div>

    }
</div>
```

Then in your controller you'll return something like this:

```
return PartialView(ajaxComment);
```

This will save you maintaining a script to do this manually and will funnel you into using the framework as intended. It will also help you out with data annotation validation and all of the juicy stuff that goes with it,

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will keep this in mind next time. For now I'll just stick to plain jquery ajax.

Comment: I do think Jquery ajax is rich in it's flexibility but when it comes to Validation Summary codes, etc that MVC handles by itself it is a clear winner when comparing RenderPartialView with Json return type.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh I agree with both of your statements. I hadn't used the method above before and it was WAY easier than wiring it up myself. I wish I had know about this sooner. Thanks again to OP

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

The Model

```
public class Comment
{
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public long PostId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

The View and js

```
@model SubmitMvcForWithJQueryAjax.Models.Comment

@using (Html.BeginForm("BlogComment","Blog"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <legend class="AddAComment">Add a comment</legend>

    <div class="commentformwrapper">

        <div class="editor-text">
        <span class="editor-label">User Name:</span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-text">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-text">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CommentText, new { rows="6", cols="23"} )
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DateCreated)        
        </div>

         <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PostId)          
        </div>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Create" />

    </div>

}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('form').submit(function () {
            var serializedForm = $(this).serialize();                       
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CommentForm")',
                type: "POST",                                       
                data: serializedForm,
                success: function (result) {

                    alert("success " + result.UserName);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Failed");
                }

            });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

The Controller

```
public class CommentController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Comment/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Comment());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CommentForm(Comment comment)
    {
        Comment ajaxComment = new Comment();
        ajaxComment.CommentText = comment.UserName;
        ajaxComment.DateCreated = comment.DateCreated ?? DateTime.Now;
        ajaxComment.PostId = comment.PostId;
        ajaxComment.UserName = comment.UserName;

        //mRep.Add(ajaxComment);
        //uow.Save();
        //Get all the comments for the given post id

        return Json(ajaxComment);


    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I believe my view has to be strongly typed (comment) for the serialization to work and this is not my case.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
data: {
          PostId: $('.postid').val(),
          UserName: $('#username').val(),
          DateCreated: new Date(),
          CommentText: $('#comment').val()
      },
```

Try

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var obj = {
        PostId: $('.postid').val(),
        UserName: $('#username').val(),
        DateCreated: new Date(),
        CommentText: $('#comment').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        ...,
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        ...,
    });

    return false;
});
```

You have to convert data to string before sending it to server. and `JSON.stringify` does that job

Comment: I had already tried it exactly like this and it wasn't working. Strangely enough I tried what DotNet Dreamer said and it worked.

Comment: This is strange and absurd. What DotNet Dreamer said is exactly what I said. Which means, If his solution is working then my solution is working.