# jQuery validation with loading spinner

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

So I understand many questions have been asked separately about the Jquery validation library and a page-loading spinner, and I can get both items to work independently, however I've not had great success using the two items together.

In short, I have an email form that is using the jQuery validation library. When "Send" is pressed, I would like a loading GIF (already on page, but `display: none`) to become visible while the controller does its business (but only if the fields are valid). From what I can tell, I need to be using `.valid()` after I validate the page per the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/), however it requires `.validate()` be run first. If I approach the problem in the following way, the form submits before the GIF ever plays:

```
<script>$("#emailForm").validate();</script>
<script>
    $("#Send").click(function () {
        if($("#emailForm").valid()) { $(".loaderWheel").show(); }
    });
</script>
```

And if I approach this way, the GIF will become visible even if the form is not valid, and will never disappear again:

```
<script>$("#emailForm").validate();</script>
<script>
    $("#Send").click(function () {
        $(".loaderWheel").show();
        if(!$("#emailForm").valid()) { $(".loaderWheel").hide(); }
    });
</script>
```

How can I make the GIF only visible when the form is valid and while the postback page is loading?

Comment: Is `#Send` and submit button or are you submitting via ajax?

Comment: #Send is the submit button.

Comment: When you submit the form is leaves the page so the spinner is never shown. I assume you controller is doing `return View()` but that returns a new page, not the page you are currently on.

Comment: Ok, so what should I change about my structure? You're right, on send, it goes to a HttpPost ActionResult method that returns the same view with a status (confirmation, failure) message.

Comment: I'm unsure why you would want to do this, but if you [submit the form via ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122949/submit-form-with-jquery-ajax), then you stay on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the submitHandler method in the validator. It executes only if the form is valid. So, this, or something like it should work. Check the documentation.

```
$().ready(function() {
  $("#profile").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $("#spinner").show();
      form.submit();
    },
    rules: {
      f_firstName: {
        required  : true,
        minlength : 2
      },
      f_lastName: {
        required  : true,
        minlength : 2
      ...
```