# ASP.Net MVC, submit form with JQuery.Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to submit a form (Html.BeginForm()) using JQuery Ajax.
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122949/submit-form-with-jquery-ajax), it should work !
I don't understand why the parameters 'email' from the action SendEmail() doesn't get values from the js.
Can you please help me ?

My View :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", @id = "formSendMail" }))
{ %>
<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="MailFrom">
                De...</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("MailFrom", Session["email"].ToString(), new { @id = "MailFrom", @Name = "MailFrom", @readonly = "readonly" })%>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="MailTo">
                A...</label>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Agent.Email, new { @id = "MailTo", @Name = "MailTo" })%>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="MailSubject">
                Objet :</label>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.MailSubject, new { @id = "MailSubject", @Name = "MailSubject" })%>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <%= Html.TextArea("MailBody", Model.MailBody, 5, 10, null)%>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

My controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(Email email)
{
    if (email != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.MailBody) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Subject) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.To))
        {
            using (IEmailDal emailDal = new EmailDal())
            {
                emailDal.SendEmail(email);
            }

            return Json("Email envoyé", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
            return Json("Error");
    }
    else
        return Json("Error");
}
```

My Email class :

```
public class Email
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MailBody { get; set; }
}
```

To submit my form, I simulate the submit action via a button in jquery.dialog :

```
$("#mail-form").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "Envoyer le mail": function () {
            $("#formSendMail").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

And my javascript :

```
$('#formSendMail').submit(function (e) {
    var myEmail = {
        From: $('#MailFrom').val(),
        To: $('#MailTo').val(),
        Subject: $('#MailSubject').val(),
        MailBody: $('#MailBody').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= Url.Action("SendEmail", "Messages") %>',
        data: JSON.stringify(myEmail),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Mail envoyé.");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Echec lors de l'envoi du mail.");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Thank you !

Comment: Your form doesn't have a submit button

Comment: And as a side note - that answer is not strictly correct - you do not need to stringify the data if you remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: @Coulton: It doesn't have a submit button because I'm using JQuery.Dialog, and I simulate the submit method via a button in the dialog : $("#mail-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 1140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Envoyer le mail": function () {
                        $("#formSendMail").submit();
                    }
                }
            });

Comment: ok, when you use the developer tools (F12) in chrome, what information is being submitted?

Comment: @Stephen: IT WORKS !! Thank you so much !! I remove contentType and the stringify and now it's ok !! But I don't understand why !!

Comment: @Flesym, Put you code in the question, not in comments

Comment: @StephenMuecke strikes again!  Boom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer (thanks Stephen Muecke) :

I just need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`, then no need to stringify the data :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%= Url.Action("SendEmail", "Messages") %>',
    data: myEmail,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Mail envoyé.");
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Echec lors de l'envoi du mail.");
    }
});
```

Now, why it didn't work in the first place, I don't know !

Answer (score 0):

if action method run correct ,your problem is the wrong path of the URLs .This is the correct URL's.

```
 url: '@Url.Action("SendEmail", "SampleController")',
```

the first parameter with called SendEmail is your action method,the second parameter is called SampleControl containing SendEmail method.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are handling on submit event if this is on pop up button then handle it directly, I mean post it by Ajax directly and if you are using JSON.Stringify then on Action level handle it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(string email)
{
    Email formData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Email>(email);
    //Now you have the object handle it how you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the names of properties of email class same with the name of your textbox field name then you will get the values in controller.

```
public class Email
{
    public string MailFrom { get; set; }
    public string MailTo { get; set; }
    public string MailSubject { get; set; }
    public string MailBody { get; set; }
}
```